# WCF - AspNetCompatibility AND net.tcp binding

Tags: asp.net, wcf, .net-4.5

I need to expose my WCF service to ASP.Net compatibility (because I need to store objects in `ApplicationState`)

If I do this, can I also use this same service with a net.tcp endpoint? And when using that net.tcp endpoint, will it still go through the Global.asax thus giving me access to `ApplicationState` values?

Comment: What do you mean by "expose to ASP.NET compatibility"?

Comment: AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.Required - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.aspnetcompatibilityrequirementsattribute.aspx